# Identity Server + Azure AD - Claims not refreshed?

Tags: identity-server

I have configured a Sitecore 9.1 Identity Server to utilize Azure AD for authentication.  Within Azure AD I have created a handful of roles, and assigned them to the necessary users.  These roles are mapped back to Identity Server, and everything appears to be working.

I have created these roles:

- Author
- Approver
- Power User

When I go back to Azure AD and change around an existing user's group memberships, however, it appears that Sitecore does not recognize the new claims.  For instance, if a user is within my Author group in Azure and logs into Sitecore, they are logged into Sitecore as an Author.  If I change the account within Azure AD to no longer have the Author role, but instead have the Power User role- it doesn't seem to affect anything.  Every time the user logs in, they're still seen as having the Author role.  The same thing is happening when I switch out any of the roles for a user.

It appears that the roles (and other claims?) are only read at the time the user is created within Sitecore, and are not updated when the user logs in subsequent times.  Is this expected behavior?

On a side note- if I cycle Identity Server the claims are re-read correctly, and the user receives updates to their role membership on the next login.

Comment: are you using `Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityProviders.DefaultClaimsTransformation` as type for AzureGroupTransformation? if yes then try by adding ` <keepSource>true</keepSource>` after `</NewClaims>`

Comment: Docs mention to recycle the app pool or appservice

Comment: edit in my above comment - try  `<keepSource>false</keepSource>`

Comment: Doesn't work @MahendraShekhawat :(